# UWP Datagrid Format Column Content

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

I am trying to write a music player. Now my music list looks like this:

[image: My DataGrid View]

However, I don't want the music duration getting displayed like an int. I want it to be something like "3:15". How can I convert it into the time format?

This is my failed attempt:

```
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                MaxWidth="120"
                Binding="{Binding Duration}"
                Header="Duration">
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MusicDurationConverter}}" />
                    </Style>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
```

I have created the converter class but this converter cannot be found. (The converter and the xaml are under the same folder.)

```
class MusicDurationConverter : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            int seconds;
            if (int.TryParse((string)value, out seconds)) return ToTime(seconds);
        }
        if (value is int) return ToTime((int)value);
        return "";
    }

    private string ToTime(int seconds)
    {
        int second = seconds % 60;
        int minute = (seconds - second) / 60;
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}", minute, second);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Additionally, I hope the "False"s in the Favorite column to disappear. When the mouse hovers above that cell, a heart button is displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have successfully created the converter class, but you don't seem to have created an instance of it in the resource list.

Try add:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <MusicDurationConverter x:Key="MusicDuarationConverter"/>
</Page.Resources/>
```

And modify the location of the binding:

```xml
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
                MaxWidth="120"
                Binding="{Binding Duration, Converter={StaticResource MusicDurationConverter}}"
                Header="Duration">
</controls:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your response but MusicDurationConverter still couldn't be found. I guess there is a type mismatch here but I don't know how to fix it. FYI the Duration is an int.

Comment: Oh I think maybe I should change TargetType to DataGridCell? Now the `MusicDurationConverter` could be found in the xaml but do you have any idea why I got `Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key MusicDurationConverter`? I have added the resource.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, you need to modify your binding method